# Captura de dados JSON com PHP

Tags: php, json

Tenho o seguinte arquivo JSON:

```
{
    "version": "1.0",
    "encoding": "UTF-8",
    "entry": {
        "xmlns": "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom",
        "xmlns$gd": "http://schemas.google.com/g/2005",
        "xmlns$yt": "http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007",
        "xmlns$media": "http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/",
        "gd$etag": "W/\"CkYBQn47eCp7I2A9XRdbE0U.\"",
        "id": {
            "$t": "tag:youtube.com,2008:video:X9sNcWUuIoY"
        },
        "published": {
            "$t": "2014-12-12T10:29:13.000Z"
        },
        "updated": {
            "$t": "2014-12-12T10:29:13.000Z"
        },
        "category": [{
                "scheme": "http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind",
                "term": "http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#video"
            }, {
                "scheme": "http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/categories.cat",
                "term": "Games",
                "label": "Jogos"
            }],
        "title": {
            "$t": "Minecraft Premium Account Generator December 2014 No Survey"
        },
        "content": {
            "type": "application/x-shockwave-flash",
            "src": "https://www.youtube.com/v/X9sNcWUuIoY?version=3&f=videos&app=youtube_gdata"
        },
        "link": [{
                "rel": "alternate",
                "type": "text/html",
                "href": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X9sNcWUuIoY&feature=youtube_gdata"
            }, {
                "rel": "http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#video.related",
                "type": "application/atom+xml",
                "href": "https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/X9sNcWUuIoY/related?v=2"
            }, {
                "rel": "http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#mobile",
                "type": "text/html",
                "href": "https://m.youtube.com/details?v=X9sNcWUuIoY"
            }, {
                "rel": "http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#uploader",
                "type": "application/atom+xml",
                "href": "https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/U9JGqO-lDU1zxB_afGr99g?v=2"
            }, {
                "rel": "self",
                "type": "application/atom+xml",
                "href": "https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/X9sNcWUuIoY?v=2"
            }],
        "author": [{
                "name": {
                    "$t": "Pijdusa Goruk"
                },
                "uri": {
                    "$t": "https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/U9JGqO-lDU1zxB_afGr99g"
                },
                "yt$userId": {
                    "$t": "U9JGqO-lDU1zxB_afGr99g"
                }
            }],
        "yt$accessControl": [{
                "action": "comment",
                "permission": "allowed"
            }, {
                "action": "commentVote",
                "permission": "allowed"
            }, {
                "action": "videoRespond",
                "permission": "moderated"
            }, {
                "action": "rate",
                "permission": "allowed"
            }, {
                "action": "embed",
                "permission": "allowed"
            }, {
                "action": "list",
                "permission": "allowed"
            }, {
                "action": "autoPlay",
                "permission": "allowed"
            }, {
                "action": "syndicate",
                "permission": "allowed"
            }],
        "gd$comments": {
            "gd$feedLink": {
                "rel": "http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#comments",
                "href": "https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/X9sNcWUuIoY/comments?v=2",
                "countHint": 0
            }
        },
        "media$group": {
            "media$category": [{
                    "$t": "Games",
                    "label": "Jogos",
                    "scheme": "http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/categories.cat"
                }],
            "media$content": [{
                    "url": "https://www.youtube.com/v/X9sNcWUuIoY?version=3&f=videos&app=youtube_gdata",
                    "type": "application/x-shockwave-flash",
                    "medium": "video",
                    "isDefault": "true",
                    "expression": "full",
                    "duration": 80,
                    "yt$format": 5
                }, {
                    "url": "rtsp://r2---sn-jc47eu7e.c.youtube.com/CiILENy73wIaGQmGIi5lcQ3bXxMYDSANFEgGUgZ2aWRlb3MM/0/0/0/video.3gp",
                    "type": "video/3gpp",
                    "medium": "video",
                    "expression": "full",
                    "duration": 80,
                    "yt$format": 1
                }, {
                    "url": "rtsp://r2---sn-jc47eu7e.c.youtube.com/CiILENy73wIaGQmGIi5lcQ3bXxMYESARFEgGUgZ2aWRlb3MM/0/0/0/video.3gp",
                    "type": "video/3gpp",
                    "medium": "video",
                    "expression": "full",
                    "duration": 80,
                    "yt$format": 6
                }],
            "media$credit": [{
                    "$t": "U9JGqO-lDU1zxB_afGr99g",
                    "role": "uploader",
                    "scheme": "urn:youtube",
                    "yt$display": "Pijdusa Goruk"
                }],
            "media$description": {
                "$t": "Legit Download Link : http://bit.ly/legit-link\nFree Download\nhttp://bit.ly/legit-link\n\nor\n\nhttp://bit.ly/legit-link\n\nExtra tags :\n\nfree minecraft account 2014,\nfree minecraft premium account,\nfree minecraft premium account generator,\nget minecraft premium,\nhoe o make minecraft account,\nminecraft account,\nminecraft account password,\nminecraft account card,\nminecraft account checker,\nminecraft account code,\nminecraft account code pc,\nminecraft account cracker,\nminecraft account emails and passwords,\nminecraft account free,\nminecraft account generator,\nminecraft account generator no survey or password,\nminecraft account generator no survey,\nminecraft account gift card,\nminecraft account giveaway,\nminecraft account hacker,\nminecraft account info,\nminecraft account list 2014,\nminecraft account login,\nminecraft account names,\nminecraft account pc,\nminecraft account premium,\nminecraft account setup,\nminecraft account\nminecraft account and passwords\nminecraft account and passwords list 2014\nminecraft account and passwords list free\nminecraft account free 2014\nminecraft premium 2014\nminecraft premium account\nminecraft premium account card\nminecraft premium account code\nminecraft premium account free\nminecraft premium account generator\nminecraft premium account generator .exe\nminecraft premium account 1.6.2\nminecraft premium account generator 2014\nminecraft premium account generator no survey\nminecraft premium account generator no survey no password\nminecraft premium account generator download\nminecraft premium account generator free\nminecraft premium account generator mac\nminecraft premium account generator no download\nminecraft premium account generator no survey\nminecraft premium account generator no survey no password\nminecraft premium account generator no surveys 2014\nminecraft premium account generator 2014\nminecraft premium account generator online\nminecraft premium account generator torrent\nminecraft premium account generator update 2014",
                "type": "plain"
            },
            "media$keywords": {},
            "media$license": {
                "$t": "youtube",
                "type": "text/html",
                "href": "http://www.youtube.com/t/terms"
            },
            "media$player": {
                "url": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X9sNcWUuIoY&feature=youtube_gdata_player"
            },
            "media$thumbnail": [{
                    "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/X9sNcWUuIoY/default.jpg",
                    "height": 90,
                    "width": 120,
                    "time": "00:00:40",
                    "yt$name": "default"
                }, {
                    "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/X9sNcWUuIoY/mqdefault.jpg",
                    "height": 180,
                    "width": 320,
                    "yt$name": "mqdefault"
                }, {
                    "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/X9sNcWUuIoY/hqdefault.jpg",
                    "height": 360,
                    "width": 480,
                    "yt$name": "hqdefault"
                }, {
                    "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/X9sNcWUuIoY/sddefault.jpg",
                    "height": 480,
                    "width": 640,
                    "yt$name": "sddefault"
                }, {
                    "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/X9sNcWUuIoY/1.jpg",
                    "height": 90,
                    "width": 120,
                    "time": "00:00:20",
                    "yt$name": "start"
                }, {
                    "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/X9sNcWUuIoY/2.jpg",
                    "height": 90,
                    "width": 120,
                    "time": "00:00:40",
                    "yt$name": "middle"
                }, {
                    "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/X9sNcWUuIoY/3.jpg",
                    "height": 90,
                    "width": 120,
                    "time": "00:01:00",
                    "yt$name": "end"
                }],
            "media$title": {
                "$t": "Minecraft Premium Account Generator December 2014 No Survey",
                "type": "plain"
            },
            "yt$aspectRatio": {
                "$t": "widescreen"
            },
            "yt$duration": {
                "seconds": "80"
            },
            "yt$uploaded": {
                "$t": "2014-12-12T10:29:13.000Z"
            },
            "yt$uploaderId": {
                "$t": "UCU9JGqO-lDU1zxB_afGr99g"
            },
            "yt$videoid": {
                "$t": "X9sNcWUuIoY"
            }
        },
        "yt$statistics": {
            "favoriteCount": "0",
            "viewCount": "1"
        }
    }
}
```

Quero capturar, com PHP, o nome do autor, que no caso está no nó `author` `0` `name` `$t`.

O código que tenho até o momento:

```
<?php

// código do vídeo 
$video_ID = 'your-video-ID';

// substitua pelo código do vídeo 
// trazendo o json com as informações do vídeo
$JSON = file_get_contents("gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos{$video_ID}?v=2&alt=json");

// decodificando e transformado o json em um objeto / array 
$JSON_Data = json_decode($JSON);

// guardando em uma variável a quantidade de views 
$views = $JSON_Data->{'entry'}->{'yt$statistics'}->{'viewCount'};

// exibindo na tela 
echo $views;

?>
```

Comment: Amigo, o que você já tentou em PHP? Já tem algum código?

Comment: Se você der um Json.Parse("seu arquivo") você consegue transformar seu json em uma lista de objetos?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a função [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) e passe true no segundo argumento para transformar o retorno em um array associativo. Depois chame a chave que deseja.

```
$arr = json_decode($json, true);
echo $arr['entry']['author'][0]['name']['$t'];
```

Answer (score 2):

Se você possui a string armazenada já em uma variável basta usar a função [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.json-decode.php) do PHP.

Esta função fará uma conversão da string em `JSON` para um `array`.

Ficando então dessa forma

```
$parseObj = json_decode($json); //Tipo objeto
$parseArray = json_decode($json, true); //Tipo Array

echo $parseObj->entry->author[0]->name->{'$t'}; //Pijdusa Goruk
echo $parseArray['entry']['author'][0]['name']['$t']; //Pijdusa Goruk
```

Answer (score 2):

O PHP conta com funções para trabalhar com JSON. O que você procura é o [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.json-decode.php).

Para chegar a chave desejada, basta navegar entre os índices do array

```
<?php

$content = file_get_contents('myJson.json');

// Segundo argumento 'true' retorna um array associativo
// ao invés de um objeto em stdClass
$array = json_decode($content, true);
echo $array['entry']['author'][0]['name']['$t'];

// Se preferir, pode usar a notação em objeto
$obj = json_decode($content);
echo $obj->entry->author[0]->name->{'$t'};
```